# How to conditionaly open a lightbox on a submit-error?

Tags: amp-html

I have an `amp-form` that submit an address with `POST`, and 2 different kind of errors that can come back : `{error: "precisionRequired"}` and `{error: "invalidZipcode"}`.

I also have 2 `amp-lightbox` with the corresponding text and forms in case of an error with the user's address, so I would like to open the correct lightbox according to the error I get.

Here is a snipet of my code :

```
<form method="POST" action-xhr="/epiceries"
  on="submit-success: AMP.navigateTo(url='/epiceries'); submit-error: precisionRequired.open">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>

<amp-lightbox id="invalidZipcode" layout="nodisplay">
  [... some form when the zipcode is not deliverable]
</amp-lightbox>

<amp-lightbox id="precisionRequired" layout="nodisplay">
  [... some content to ask the user to give us a complete address, not just a city :) ]
</amp-lightbox>
```

I know that I can use a state to conditionally render the part that I'm interested by in a single lightbox like this :

```
<form method="POST" action-xhr="/epiceries"
  on="submit-success: AMP.navigateTo(url='/epiceries'); submit-error: AMP.setState({error: event.response.error}), lightbox.open">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>

<amp-lightbox id="lightbox>
  <div [class]="error == 'invalidZipcode' ? '' : 'hidden'">
    [... some form when the zipcode is not deliverable]
  </div>

  <div [class]="error == 'precisionRequired' ? '' : 'hidden'">
    [... some content to ask the user to give us a complete address, not just a city :) ]
  </div>
</amp-lightbox>
```

but it seems hack'ish and I would like to have 2 different lightboxes, as in my first snippet.

Is it possible to conditionally open a lightbox, based on a server response ? if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own lightbox using CSS and show it based on the result:

```
<div id="lightboxErrorZipcode" class="lightbox" 
     [hidden]="error !== 'invalidZipcode'" hidden>
    [... some form when the zipcode is not deliverable]
  <button on="tap:lightboxErrorZipcode.close">Close</button>
</div>
...
```

Personally, I'd use the approach you described of conditionally rendering the lightbox content (one suggestion would be to use the hidden attribute as in my sample). This way you don't need to re-define the lightbox behaviour in CSS.

Comment: Redefining lightbox using CSS will loose the ESC or background click to close it, right ?

So I guess the only option left is 1 `amp-lightbox` with 2 `div` that conditionally hide themselves :/

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're right about ESC, good point, forgot about that. You can implement the background close action using the close though.